# Pipe video and audio to ffmpeg from OpenRTSP

Tags: ffmpeg, rtsp, live555, openrtsp

I am trying to record rtsp stream in HLS format using openRTSP and ffmpeg. openRTSP receives rtsp and pipe to ffmpeg to record,

Here is the command I used and which works fine

```
openRTSP -D 10 -v -t -c -b 800000 rtsp://wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov | .././ffmpeg -r 15 -i - -codec copy -hls_list_size 65535 -hls_time 2 "./live.m3u8"
```

Note in above commnad -v is for video only.

But now I need to record audio also so I removed -v option, but the video is not getting recorded. It's just creating two files named
`audio-MPEG4-GENERIC-1` and `video-H264-2` no HLS video file. I think some problem with piping. Can anyone help me to solve it.

Comment: Your question is confusing, hls is `HTTP Live Streaming` then it is over http but you are using an rtsp url ?

Comment: Basically my input stream is rtsp and I want to store it on hls format.

Comment: Your post is unclear, because HLS is a streaming signaling protocol not a video format. Basically a m3u8 file is just a playlist of http url to get fragment of stream. In the pipe (with the -v) there is H264 elementary stream, you can store it and stream it as HLS.

Comment: You are right, using above command I am getting the `live.m3u8` generated with all the `.ts `  file path. Also all the `.ts` generated in the same directory. So after running the above command I can see `live.m3u8, live0.ts,live1.ts,live2.ts.....` generated in the directory.  And I can play live.m3u8 using VLC. Now using the same way I have store the video as well as with audio, but while removing `-v` option and running the command I am getting only these two files generated `audio-MPEG4-GENERIC-1` and `video-H264-2`  instead `live.m3u8` and all other `.ts` files.

Comment: Have you ever found the solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but it came up in a Google search for me today. Since I can answer this I will, for any future Googlers out there.

You don't need to use openRTSP at all. ffmpeg can handle RTSP streams just fine. I recently coded up a livecam streaming site for my security cameras. The command I'm using to generate the HLS stream is this:

```
ffmpeg -v quiet -i 'rtsp://user:pass@192.168.1.110:554' -c:v copy -c:a copy \
    -bufsize 50k -pix_fmt yuv420p -flags -global_header -hls_time 5 -hls_list_size 3 \
    -hls_flags delete_segments hls.m3u8
```

This will output `hls.m3u8` and all of the `hls.ts` files. You might have to play with some of those parameters for your specific needs. Here is some good documentation for the flags: [FFmpeg Formats Documentation](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#Options-5)